# API Key Authentication for Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape

I've my AuthToken Model

```
class APIKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_access_token

  private

  def generate_access_token
    begin
      self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
  end
end
```

In my /controllers/api/v1/request.rb

```
def authenticate!
  token= AuthToken.where(:access_token => params[:token])
  error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless token
end
```

And I'm accepting parameters like this

```
resource :request do
  post :test do
    params do 
     requires :test_param, type: String,
     requires :token, type: String
    end 
    authenticate!
    Email_id.create! # It's handled properly in the controller, There's no problem in it. 
  end 
end
```

The problem is I'm not able to parse that particular token parameter into the authenticate function so that I can check in the model and then I can authenticate requests in the API key authentication model.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `authenticate!` so that it takes a parameter:

```
def authenticate!(token)
  error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless AuthToken.where(access_token: token).present?
end
```

And pass it in from the controller like that:

```
resource :request do
  params do 
   requires :test_param, type: String,
   requires :token, type: String
  end

  post :test do
    authenticate!(params[:token])
  end 
end
```

Comment: should it be like authenticate(token)
error!('401',401) unless AuthToken.where(access_token: parama[:token])

Comment: Actually I'm using POSTMAN to send post req to check if the request is getting blocked for wrong API key parameter, But it's not getting blocked. The request is still being processed.

Comment: @th3lazytig3r I got what's wrong. The condition should be `unless AuthToken.where(access_token: token).present?`. Because without `present?` it always evaluates to true.

Comment: I figured it just now! Coincidence :D Thanks a lot BTW :)